# How to compare my email text field value to database value in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a problem in comparing my textfield email value to the value in sqlite database. If both the values are same then it shows alertbox that "email already exist in database". I have created a function for this purpose named findcontact, I am calling the function from button click. Button click method is working because when I click the button then buttonclick method generate the log which I have written in findContact method.

But problem for me is that how to compare both the email and show alert box if both email matches

```
- (void) findContact:(NSString *) email{

    const char *dbpath = [path UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT email FROM CONTACT WHERE email=\"%@\"",email];
        NSLog(@" email = %@", querySQL);
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        NSLog(@" char email = %s", query_stmt);
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &init_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            if (sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"email already exist in database" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK ", nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
            else {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"email not exist" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK ", nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(init_statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you get in Log of this line  NSLog(@" char email = %s", query_stmt); ??

Comment: i get this 2012-12-05 12:39:23.414 Registration Form[650:207]  email = SELECT email FROM CONTACT WHERE email="aaa@y.co"
2012-12-05 12:39:23.416 Registration Form[650:207]  char email = SELECT email FROM CONTACT WHERE email="aaa@y.co"

Comment: char email = SELECT email FROM CONTACT WHERE email="aaa@y.co" i get this in log file for query_stmt

Comment: where you get the email address from database ??

Comment: 'i am getting it fron 'CONTACTS.SQLITE database actually i  have another function for inserting data into database that is working perfectly but when i selecting value from database thats not working

Answer (score 1):

Do comparison like this in your code

```
    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {

        NSString *emaiID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)];

        if ([emaiID isEqualToString:yourTextField.text])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:@"email already exist in database"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK ", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else{
            //Your task
        }
        }
```

Comment: I AM getting thread program receive signal sigabrt while enter the values in textfield and click on button

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT email FROM CONTACT WHERE email='%@'",email]; 

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sharedDataBase, [querySQL UTF8String], -1, &statment, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(statment)==SQLITE_ROW){

            char *email=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 0); 

            NSString  *emailStr =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:email]; 

            // email exist 

        }
        else{

            // email not exist
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statment); 
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(sharedDataBase);
```